# Blender grease pencil shape keys

Tags: rigging, shape-keys, grease-pencil, 2d

is there any possible way to achieve a similar result like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tbp95snCPr4 with grease pencil?

Or is there somewhere shape keys for the internal grease pencil tool?

It would be awesome for an animation to have that - you know, custom strokes, but with rigged shapes whole new dimension in the speed of rigging 2D puppets.

Comment: This video might do it for you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgfzqGxpUxk

Comment: well thank you for the post, but its rigged line by bones that is too technical solution for the artists I think. It takes too much time, and I don't think with this you can achieve the same result quality.

Comment: With 2.81 in grease pencil are vertex groups, so I have a little bit different question, is it possible to make the default blender bezier line with grease pencil stroke (textured, pressure or so)